# Different almost complex structures: $\mathbb C$-isomorphism for $(W,K)$ and $(W,H)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-geometry, almost-complex

I started studying the book of Daniel Huybrechts, Complex Geometry An Introduction. I tried studying [backwards](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13089/why-do-so-many-textbooks-have-so-much-technical-detail-and-so-little-enlightenme) as much as possible, but I have been stuck on the concepts of [almost complex structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure) and [complexification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification). I have studied several books and articles on the matter including ones by [Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf), [Jordan Bell](https://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/complexification.pdf), [Gregory W. Moore](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~gmoore/618Spring2019/GTLect2-LinearAlgebra-2019.pdf), [Steven Roman](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387728285), [Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881246834), [Gauthier](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319115108).

I have several questions on the concepts of almost complex structures and complexification. Here is one:

**Assumptions for question**: Let $W = (W,\text{Add}_W: W^2 \to W,s_W: \mathbb R \times W \to W)$ be $\mathbb R$-vector space, which may be infinite-dimensional. Suppose $W$ has an almost complex structure $H: W \to W$ uniquely corresponding to the $\mathbb C$-vector space $(W,H)$ where scalar multiplication is given by the complex structure $s_W^{H}: \mathbb C \times W \to W$, $s_W^{H}(a+ib,v) := s_W(a,v) + s_W(b,H(v))$ that agrees with the original real scalar multiplication $s_W$. I understand that ([at least for finite-dimensional $W$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3559378/for-any-two-almost-complex-structures-on-infinite-dimensional-space-do-they-giv)) $K: W \to W$ is another almost complex structure on $W$ if and only if $K=S \circ H \circ S^{-1}$ for some $S \in Aut_{\mathbb R}W$ based on [Moore (Section 9.1)](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~gmoore/618Spring2019/GTLect2-LinearAlgebra-2019.pdf).

**Question**: Based on [Gauthier](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319115108) (specifically [Chapter 14.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6tPL.png) which is for finite-dimensional), it seems $(W,K)$ and $(W,H)$ are $\mathbb C$-isomorphic, but not necessarily by the identity map ([at least for finite-dimensional $W$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3559378/for-any-two-almost-complex-structures-on-infinite-dimensional-space-do-they-giv)). Actually, are $(W,K)$ and $(W,H)$ $\mathbb C$-isomorphic by the identity map if and only if $K=H$ (whether finite-dimensional or infinite-dimensional)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes because $id: (W,K) \to (W,H)$ is indeed $\mathbb R$-linear and thus is $\mathbb C$-linear if and only if $id$ commutes with scalar multiplication by i, i.e. for all $w \in W$,

$$id(i \cdot w) = i \cdot id(w) \tag{A}$$

For the left hand side is $i \cdot w := K(w)$ and for the right hand side, $i \cdot id(w) := H(id(w))$. Therefore, condition $(A)$ is equivalent to $(id \circ K) (w) = (H \circ id)(w)$, which is equivalent to $K(w)=H(w)$